# How can i set the content of reactstrap modal-header in center?

Tags: reactjs, html, css, reactstrap, react-modal

I'm using the reactstrap Modal,There is ModalHeader where I am showing my content.But I am facing the issue while i'm trying to put that content in center of header.

After doing inspect elements I found inside ModalHeader there is `<h5>` tag, inside this tag my contents are coming, I checked `<h5>` tag is not using the full width of Modal-Header.I think because of that its not coming in center. If someone know about reactstrap Modal please guide me how can I put my Modal-Header content in center.Thanks in Advance.

Here is my sample code.

```
<ModalHeader toggle={props.toggle} > 
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
 <img src={myImg} alt="img" className="imgSize" /> 
</div> 
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center"> 
<p>Hi <b>John -</b> here is my some text</p>
</div> 
</ModalHeader>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add className to h2 tag with cssModule props. Adding `w-100 text-center` solve the issue for me

```
<ModalHeader toggle={props.toggle}  cssModule={{'modal-title': 'w-100 text-center'}}> 
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
 <img src={myImg} alt="img" className="imgSize" /> 
</div> 
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center"> 
<p>Hi <b>John -</b> here is my some text</p>
</div> 
</ModalHeader>
```

Comment: Hi @aseferov thanks for reply,I applied this class now header content is coming to center but the closing modal icon is coming below header content.

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: Its also working fine if i do like this in my css file.
 /* 
.modal-header h5{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
} 
*/

is it good practice if I do like this or do what you have answered?

Comment: Adding it to css file can make global affect for other modals. Also its not maintainable